# three.js THREE.FBXLoader 3d model not showing

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to add THREE.FBXLoader 3D model into three js project but its showing error

```
THREE.FBXLoader: External library Inflate.min.js required, obtain or import from https://github.com/imaya/zlib.js
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3r0Rg.png)

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned by the error message, just including the `examples/js` version of `THREE.FBXLoader` is not sufficient because the loader has a dependency. You need to include this dependency with a separate `<script>` tag.